Returning back to employer -with a higher job position- after leaving is a problem for MBA program admission?
I was ranked 1st on my B.Eng class and worked as a teaching assistant for 2 years at my university located in Egypt but left it to work in the industry to gain more practical knowledge for 1 year and got a better job offer from my university with managerial responsibilities. Now I'm applying for an MBA program at another university in the USA. Will the university admission might have a negative perspective on me?

will the university admission might have a negative perspective on me? can you highlight which aspect you think might have a negative perspective?

The aspect is as follows, fear of showing dichotomy as not many employees leave their employers and get back after 1 year for a higher, managerial role and get accepted with ease, especially in Egypt with its tough economic situation. that's the reason why I'm asking as I am not fully aware of the nature of the job market in the US.

You should add to your post what your future plans are and specific concerns you have.  There is nothing wrong with being accepted for an MBA in the US per se, but turning down a good job offer from the Egypt university may make it difficult to get another offer from them in the future. This may or may not matter to you. You need to clarify whose "perspective" you are asking about.

Generally speaking, No.  Most MBA programs like for students to have experience outside the halls of academic institutions.
Why do you think that it would have a negative reflection on yourself?

Highly appreciative for replying. Well, I'm the only one who's done that in my network and asked multiple people and the answers were repudiative.

As clarified in the comments

"The aspect is as follows, fear of showing dichotomy as not many employees leave their employers and get back after 1 year for a higher, managerial role and get accepted with ease, especially in Egypt with its tough economic situation. that's the reason why I'm asking as I am not fully aware of the nature of the job market in the US."

You might be surprised to know the actual number of people (at least, in IT industry), who return to the same organization after a certain period, with more relevant knowledge and experience, in a higher role!  In case this is is related to pursuing a higher education or industry experience, and you left in good terms, there should be absolutely no problem in joining back (or, politely refusing the offer and join somewhere else altogether). Please do not overthink it, this is usually normal scenario.

Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, I've left on good terms and actually, there was some resistance from the Dean and the 4 professors that I've worked with not letting me leave but I made it explicit that my career needed further technical development in the industry and the new role is way better in terms of career progression. Thank you once again.
